# Detect collision between two bodies in Box2d and libgdx(android)

Tags: android, libgdx, box2d

I am new to libgdx and Box2d engine and I'm developing a game using same .I want to detect collision between two bodies to perform some function.But I'm not aware about the optimum way to do that and also want get point of collision.Kindly provide some suggestion with code.I have already implemented ContactListener but to no avail.

I'm using [this](https://github.com/droidinteractive/Box2DLights/blob/master/box2dlights/src/com/droidinteractive/box2dlight/test/Box2dLightAndroidTest.java) code as a reference.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You already did it the right way to create and set a ContactListener... (for a general setup, the libgdx wiki is great: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/box2d#contact-listeners)

If you now want to handle the specific contacts, you for exmaple need to add some implementation in the `beginContact();` method of your listener. The `beginContact();` method contains a `Contact`  instance, which holds all you need:

- FixtureA - the first fixture of a contact
- FixtureB - the fixture, which FixtureA has collided with
- WorldManifold - an object that holds the collision points etc

Through the fixtures you can access the bodies and the actors which you are drawing. The connection to your Actor can be done through the `body.setUserData(actor);` method.

Now you need to decide on how to find out the correct collisions. You can either work with sensors, which are box2d fixtures that just act as a sensor. That means that when an object collides with a sensor, it won't bounce, but fall through it instead. But you then are able to detect this contact within the listener.

Also, it might be a good idea to add some kind of GameObjectType to your actors. Imagine you create a jumping game where the player jumps from platform to platform with water below. Then you would create your actors with types like PLAYER, WATER, PLATFORM ... through the getUserData() method of the box2d bodies yu can now access the Actors and compare their types.

E.g. when an Actor of type PLAYER collides with one of type WATER, he will drown...

Hope it helps...

Comment: :Thanks for your plausible answer.It would be really helpful if you could suggest some more code or explanation regarding sensors.

Comment: And what exactly body.getUserData returns ?

Comment: A sensor is a fixture with which other objects won't collide. You add them just as other fixtures to the body, but set the isSensor flag in the FixtureDef. When running the simulation, other object will fall through the sensors, not collide and bounce off. But in a ContactListener, you can check whether one fixture that collided is a sensor using `isSensor()` ...

Comment: `getUserData()` will return anything you set as the user data. In my projects I usually have a GameObject class that extends a `Group`... and it holds a `Body` element. Sure, this way you are not separating rendering and simulation, but it comes in handy and is easy to use... When creating the fixtures and the body within a subclass of `GameObject`, I use the `setUserData(this)` method, to add the GameObject itself as user data to the box2d body. This way, I can access the GameObject through casting the result of getUserData() within the ContactListener...